# Solr search exact word not including phrases

Tags: c#, solr, full-text-search, config

I wanted to know if there is a way in solr config to have an exact match discarding those that are in phrases.

Example:
search string: "Hello"
result should be: "Hello"
and should not contain: "Hello world", "Hi, Hello"

It should search an exact match to the word but ignore this in phrases.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the field Type to string.

Make sure you have the below entry

```
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
```

The StrField type is not analyzed, but indexed/stored.

Then change the field type for the field key.

```
<field name="fieldName" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

With this it will be exact search as there wont be any token.

or the option could be use the below field type

```
<fieldType name="lowercase" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100"> 
<analyzer> 
      <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/> 
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" /> 
</analyzer> 
</fieldType>
```

Here KeywordTokenizer does no actual tokenizing, so the entire             input string is preserved as a single token.

and the LowerCase TokenFilter does what you expect, which can be             when you want your sorting/searching to be case insensitive

Comment: can you share the schema.xml...? did you re-index the same?

Comment: <field name="fieldName" multiValued="true" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" />. I just changed the type 'text' to 'string' then stop/start the tomcat service

Comment: but you need to re-index the data or you can analyse the same in solr web interface...

Comment: im not too familiar with solr. I executed a full data-import, is that enough?

Comment: yes that's enough...after doing the same, still you are not able to achieve  it?

Comment: Additional question, how do I replicate this into a new field type that is also case insensitive

Comment: in that case you use the fieldType <fieldType name="lowercase" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85067/discussion-between-milo-cabs-and-abhijit-bashetti).

Answer (score 2):

I was initially thinking about proximity, but that is not required for your case.

define a field of type String say amn_name_ss --This is a stored String

String will look out for exact search when searched with ""

Eg: amn_name_ss:"Hello" will return only docs which exactly has value Hello

Create Docs as 
{"id":"amn1","amn_name_ss":"Hello","type":"AMN"}
{"id":"amn2","amn_name_ss":"Hello World","type":"AMN"}

Query:
http://hostname:8080/solr/collection1/select?q=*%3A*&fq=type%3AAMN&wt=json&indent=true

will give result as below
[image]

Query:
http://hostname:8080/solr/collection1/select?q=amn_name_ss%3A%22Hello%22&fq=type%3AAMN&wt=json&indent=true

will give result as below

[image]

Comment: sorry, im not too familiar with solr. can you explain how to do the proximity settings?

Comment: So making the search field to a string type would resolve this? No need for Tokenizers/analyzers/filter changes?

Comment: Yes, making the field type to string will resolve exact comparison issues. We use Tokenizers with text fields, say you want to store "Google and Samsung" and the result should be retrieved while searching for both Samsung as well as and as well as Google. When you decode searching with "and" is not required, you will add stopwords filter